# Find new coordinate (x', y') given (x, y) , theta, and velocity?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, robotics

Given (x,y) that is (3,4) , velocity is 1 m/sec and given angle is 15 degree. what will be next coordinate (x', y') after 1 sec ?
Anyone please help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about [Mathematics.SE]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the angle is measure w.r.t. the x-axis, then:

- the total distance is `v*t = 1m`
- displacement in x-direction: `cos(15)*1m=.97m`
- displacement in y-direction: `sin(15)*1m=.25m`

So the new location is `(3.97, 4.25)`.

Comment: Thanks.. but angle intially is arctan(4/3) = 53.1 degeree but after angular motion now angle should be 53.1+15 = 68.1 degree but it is arctan(4.25/3.97) = 46.9

Comment: In  your question you do not specify that there was supposed to be a change in angle. But you could plug in the new angle directly to get the coordinates.

Comment: ok, plz tell suppose a car is initially at 53 degree w.r.t x-axis that is (3,4) and it moved 15 degree more towards x-axis at 1 m/sec then how we solve this...

Comment: I believe I just did... If it initially has `53°`, then (abruptly) is turned by `15°` towards the x-axis, its resulting angle with the x-axis is `53°-15°=38°`. If it then travels linearly for one second, its final position is `(3.8,4.6)`.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander-Vogt's answer is close but I think it is missing a conversion from angles to radians. Here is matlab code that provides the answer:

```
pi=3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971;
x=3;y=4;
t=1; % time
s=1*t; % speed * time
a=15; % angle of movement
a=a/360 * pi*2; % convert to radians
x=cos(a)*s+x;
y=sin(a)*s+y;
fprintf("%f %f\n",x,y);
```